# ["'<built-in function id>' is not a valid UUID."]

Tags: django

I am trying to patch an existing but i get an unknown problem .Does anybody know why?

**Models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**Views.py**

```
class ArticleView(CreateAPIView):
  serializer_class = ArticleCreateSerializer
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

  def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)
        serializer = ArticleCreateSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            article = serializer.save()
            return Response(ArticleCreateSerializer(article).data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Error:**

```
["'<built-in function id>' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Comment: do you use Postgres?

Comment: Nope.I use Mongodb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)`

`id` here is built-in [python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

```
article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs.get('id'))
```

will be right.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is related to the [Python builtin `id` function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) It's trying to use this `id` because there's no `id` in scope here - `id` isn't declared here or passed in as an argument.

Assuming you're using DRF's views normally, you should be able to do this instead:

```
article = self.get_object()
```